# Android facebook login get code not access token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm using facebook sdk on a Android app to login. Everything works ok with the login but instead of the access token on successful login I would like the get a code like when building a manually login flow (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#confirm). Here you have the possibility to set the response_type to token or code.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
client_id={app-id} & redirect_uri={redirect-uri} & reponse_type=code
```

Is there a possibility to also set this when using the facebook sdk?

Thank you!

Comment: Looking into the SDK's code, I don't believe this is possible.