# Login with Facebook flow

Tags: android, facebook, authorization, registration, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have a server with REST api & a native android app.

What I want is to give users ability to register and login using their facebook account: if user is not registered yet - then it taps the Login with Facebook button, grant me basic permissions and I create an account on my server; if the user is already registered - then he just logs in and can use the app.

Can you give me any links to resources where this flow is being described?
Because I really can't understand how it should work.
Should I use facebook SDK for android, get user data from it and then send to my server? Then how do I manage user after this... 
I only need facebook for user registration and login, all app functionality will be based by custom data from my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Greatings, Graykos.

I will give you few resources what I think we will be useful for you:

1. Login with Facebook. Official docs [Facebook Developers I](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android).
2. Login Flow with Facebook. Official docs [Facebook Developers II](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow).
3. Testing a Login Flow. Official docs [Facebook Developers III](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/testing-your-login-flow).
4. The right way to implement Facebook login for your app. [LaunchKit](https://library.launchkit.io/the-right-way-to-implement-facebook-login-in-a-mobile-app-57e2eca3648b#.au3dwl2ie).
5. Old question about this teme, which is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007025/manually-build-a-login-flow-for-facebook-on-android). In this case, you probably will need to update some methods.

If you have some questions about this when you develop your Facebook login, let us know, in SO!

Have a good day!

Comment: Very nice. Especially #4 in the list. Thanks a lot to @Carlos Vázquez Losada